# Linux distro name parsing

Tags: python, regex, linux

I chose this way to get linux distro name:

```
ls /etc/*release
```

And now I have to parse it for name:

```
/etc/<name>-release

def checkDistro():
    p = Popen('ls /etc/*release' , shell = True, stdout = PIPE)
    distroRelease = p.stdout.read()

    distroName = re.search( ur"\/etc\/(.*)\-release", distroRelease).group()
    print distroName
```

But this prints the same string that is in **distroRelease**.

Comment: You might want to use the Linux Standard Base tool "lsb_release" instead. Run it with `--help` and/or `-a` to get a feel of how it works.

Comment: As you may already know, `/etc/*release` won't work for all distros. But see http://serverfault.com/questions/3331/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-is-running/3334#3334

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `.group(1)`, because you want the first capture group - without arguments, it defaults to `.group(0)` which is the entire matched text.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to use the builtin method `platform.linux_distribution()` (available in Python 2.6+):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '5.1', 'Tikanga')
```

In older versions of Python, `platform.dist()` can be used:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.dist()
('redhat', '5.1', 'Tikanga')
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing `ls` output is discouraged. Consider using a glob():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob

def check_distro():
    print os.path.basename(glob.glob('/etc/*-release')[0]).replace('-release', '')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_distro()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point? `/etc/*release` is not a standard, it will only work on some distros.

Comment: I know that. This script will work only under distros which supports this file.

Comment: @Lo'oris: that's not really up to you to judge, is it? If OP chooses to create the script this way despite the limitation, then it very likely will be useful to him.

Comment: Since there is a better way to do that, as pointed out by Magnus Hoff in his comment, this way is just wrong and should be avoided.